# Reload JTable's Object[][] after data has changed

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I am wondering if it is possible to refresh a Table's GUI when the `Object[][]` used to initially populate it has changed.

```
Object[][] calculationsTableData;
public Interface() {
    ...
    analysisPanel.add(calculationsTable());
    ...
}

JScrollPane calculationsTable() {
    populateCalculationsTableData();
    ...
    calculationsTable = new JTable(calculationsTableData, calculationsColumnNames);
    ...
}

void populateCalculationsTableData(){
    Object[][] temp = new Object[x.numsSize][7];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.numsSize; i++) {
        temp[i][0] = df.format(x.nums[i]);
        ...
    }
    calculationsTableData = temp;
}
```

`populateCalculationsTableData()` is called when the x object has changed to repopulate `calculationsTableData`

`repaint()` and `revalidate()` methods do not appear to be effective in this scenario and neither does `fireTableDataChanged()` as this is not a table model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) creates a new instance of <strike>`DefaultTableModel`</strike> [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) <sup>[**1**]</sup> implementation if no table model is explicitely set. If the table needs to be updated you have to work with its model.

#### You could...

Set a new [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html):

```
void populateCalculationsTableData() {
    ...
    calculationsTableData = temp;
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(calculationsTableData, calculationsColumnNames);
    calculationsTable.setModel(model);
}
```

#### Or you could...

Create the table using a `DefaultTableModel`:

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(calculationsTableData, calculationsColumnNames);
calculationsTable = new JTable(model);
```

Cast the table model as `DefaultTableModel` and set its data and columns like this:

```
void populateCalculationsTableData() {
    ...
    calculationsTableData = temp;
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)calculationsTable.getModel();
    model.setDataVector(calculationsTableData, calculationsColumnNames);
}
```

#### Suggested readings

- [JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable-java.lang.Object:A:A-java.lang.Object:A-)
- [DefaultTableModel#setDataVector(Object[][] dataVector, Object[] columnIdentifiers)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector-java.lang.Object:A:A-java.lang.Object:A-)
- [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

---

<sup>[**1**]</sup>: After checking `JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)` source code I've realized that no `DefaultTableModel` is created but a new anonymous inner class extending from `AbstractTableModel` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would create your own table model to wrap the object arrays, and which exposed the fireTableDataChanged() method:

```
private static class ObjectArrayModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final Object[][] rowData;
    private final Object[] columnNames;

    private ObjectArrayModel(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames) {
        this.rowData = rowData;
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
    }

    @Override
    public void fireTableDataChanged() {
        super.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
        return columnNames[column].toString();
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowData.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return rowData[row][col]; }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { return true; }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        rowData[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

... when the data changes you should be able to call fireTableDataChanged() on this and it will notify the table it needs to redraw itself.